# though it would weaken you, as Hindenburg said of poetry

Tags: meaning

> The Anglo-Saxon navies, he might argue, have
>   a certain code of rules for use at sea; they let women get first into
>   the boats, for instance, when ships are sinking, and they rescue
>   drowning mariners when they can: no actual harm in all this, he would
>   feel, though it would weaken you, as Hindenburg said of poetry; but if
>   all these little rules are tyrannously enforced on those who may think
>   them silly, what is to become of the pirate?

This is from "Tales of War" by Lord Dunsany.

I can not understand what does the sentence below means.
*....though it would  weaken you, as Hindenburg said of poetry;*

Does it mean "as Hindenburg(poet?) said about poetry"?
Poetry would weaken you?
Or
as Hindenburg(Disaster) was sung in some poem?

I am glad if some one kindly give me some advice.

Comment: My guess it refers to [Paul von Hindenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_von_Hindenburg) though I don't know the connection to poetry might be.

Comment: What a confusing paragraph!

Answer (score 2):

It probably means that Hindenburg, being a military man, felt poetry, with it's romantic wording and soft allusions, would make a warrior's heart sentimental and soft.

The more complete text in your reference is about [Grand-Admiral von Tirpitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_von_Tirpitz) who wanted to remembered along side [Captain Kidd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kidd) as a fierce pirate, thus the question

> what is to become of the pirate?

von Tirpitz felt that these little codes of practice, if followed all the time, would make a pirate's heart soft and sentimental, like Hindenburg's thoughts on poetry.

Hindenburg and von Tirpitz were contemporaries.

Comment: Thank so much for your kind and detailed answer. It made me so clear!!

Answer (score 2):

> though it would weaken you, as Hindenburg said of poetry;

It means that *it* would weaken you  just like Hindenburg said that poetry would weaken you.